# Angular HTTP Service, do something when request finished

Tags: angular, httprequest

I've managed to build a connection between my express.js Server and my Angular app (Angular APP is also hosted by the express server).

I've created a component (which does nothing right now) but my goal is to call a service method(this service method does a http get request to get a JSON string from the server) and when the method received the JSON string successfully I want to do something with it in my component.

My Service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DbConnectorService {
  private baseUrl:string = "http://localhost:3000"
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getAllData() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/api/getData').subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res.text());
    }); 
  }
}
```

Doing the HTTP request and getting the JSON works for now (JSON is inside the `res.text()`) but how do I call the method from a component and lets say print it out there when it received the JSON string successfully?

Comment: See how you're subscribing in the service. Do that in the component. So return the observable instead of subscribing.

Answer (score 1):

```
getAllData() {
  return this.http.get(...)
  .pipe(tap(res => console.log(res))); // if you want to log it immediately
}
```

inject DbConnectionService into component

and in component

```
dbConnectionService.getAllData().subscribe(// do sth with response);
```

you can also specify generic type of Observable

```
getAllData(): Observable<TypeOfData> {
  return this.http.get<TypeOfData>(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `get` method return an Observable, which is a data streaming and can only be activated by the `subscribe()` function ( think of Observable as a pipe contain data and the `subscribe()` function is it's valve , it activate the pipe and data start flowing out )

You can define the method in your service

```
getAllData() : Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(...);
}
```

Then inject and subscribe to it in your components

```
this.dbConnectionService.getAllData().subscribe(console.log);
```